# chart js bar chart not displaying array

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to create a bar chart using chart.js

My code reads like this:

```js
var myBarChart = new Chart(histChart, {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [28, 6, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]
    }]
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#histChart {
  width: 600px;
  height: 480px;
  border: 3px solid #8AC007;
}
```

```html
<!-- Include Leaflet -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Include CARTO.js -->
<script src="https://libs.cartocdn.com/carto.js/v4.1.10/carto.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/13.1.0/nouislider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/examples/maps/public/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/13.1.0/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="histChart" width="400" height="100"></canvas>

</body>
```

but when I refresh the browser, all I get is a histogram with the first value:

[image]

I have tried a for loop in the within the datasets setting, but chart.js doesn't like it. How to I get chart.js to display all of the values in the array?

Comment: `source` is not defined

Comment: @kboul see the updated version that exhibits the same behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `labels` property on the outer `data` object. This corresponds to each data point in each dataset. For example, 28 maps to "Red" and so on.

You can see [Creating a Chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/#creating-a-chart) for a better example

```js
var myBarChart = new Chart(histChart, {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Favorite Color",
      data: [28, 6, 2, 4, 2, 2]
    }]
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#histChart {
  width: 600px;
  height: 480px;
  border: 3px solid #8AC007;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="histChart" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
</body>
```